# android bufferedreader throwing exception with internet permission added

Tags: java, android

I have a Java program that works perfectly with the code below. When I add it to Android I get an exception at the BufferedReader line. I have added permissions to the manifest file. I am running the code on an actual device. The runController() method returns a String which I print on the screen. The only solution I can find is that the internet permission must be added, which I did. I don't know what I am missing. Any help will be greatly appreciated. The code I have is as follows:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.androidwebconnect"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.androidwebconnect.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

The Java code is:

```
public class ControllerLast {

private static URL urlObj;
private static URLConnection connection;

String message;
String urlString = "http://www.dailydiary.hljointventure.co.za/viewentry.php"; //the url for the website is here

public ControllerLast() {

}

public String runControllerLast() {

    try {            
        urlObj = new URL(urlString);
        connection = urlObj.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);   
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        message = ex.getMessage(); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        message = ex.getMessage();
    }

    try {       
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String lineRead = "";

        while ((lineRead = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            message = lineRead;
        }

        reader.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        message = ex.getMessage();
    }

    return message;
}   
}


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String message;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnStatus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_check);
    final TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

    btnStatus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            text.setText(message);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "an exception"?

Comment: " I have a Java program that works perfectly with the code below" - Please keep in mind that code that works in Java might NOT work in Android...

Comment: Possibility: are you doing the network call in the main thread? Android does not allow that.

Comment: Yes I am doing it in the main thread. I see one should use asynctask - thanks

Comment: I now have the network call in a method that extends AsynTask. I am still getting a null pointer exception.

Comment: The log as follows: 01-19 16:19:53.752: E/AndroidRuntime(13849): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-19 16:19:53.752: E/AndroidRuntime(13849): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
...
01-19 16:19:53.752: E/AndroidRuntime(13849): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException